# IOS YouTube Helper Library

Tags: ios, youtube

I am trying to use this Library to play youtube video in my ios app, it works for when I load the page for the first time, when I go back to the previous view controller and go into the viewcontroller again which have the youtube video, the video player doesn't show up any more, unless I kill the app and restart again. Not sure Why it is like.

I have a view controller, in the view controller I am using this library to play youtube videos. when I get into this view controller for the first time it all works fine, but when i get to this view controller for the second time, the player not showing up unless I kill the app.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.player loadPlayerWithVideoId:@"M7lc1UVf-VE"];
}

-(YTPlayerView*)player
{
    if(!_player)
    {
        _player = [[YTPlayerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.bounds.size.width, 220)];
        _player.delegate = self;
        _player.autoplay = NO;
        _player.modestbranding = YES;
        _player.allowLandscapeMode = YES;
        _player.forceBackToPortraitMode = YES;
        _player.allowAutoResizingPlayerFrame = YES;
        _player.playsinline = NO;
        _player.fullscreen = YES;
        _player.playsinline = YES;
    }
    return _player;
}
```

Comment: We cant figure it out with words, please post some code which you think might have issue.

Comment: I have edited my question, sorry for my bad explanations.

Comment: Well I don't know much about this lib, but here is a good tutorial to try as sandbox, https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

Comment: Have you gone through the same steps give in this link?https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

Comment: I did tried that and the sample project as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this library to load youtube video and it's working fine for me in the situation you described....

You should declare YTPlayerView as property in .h file like this.

@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet YTPlayerView *playerView;

It is working well for me.

Comment: I have tried that, I am not sure if it because every time I push to this view controller I created a new player instance, so when the second time I created a new instance of the player, it doesn't show up for me.

Comment: Have you gone through the same steps give in this link?developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

Comment: I have been reading the whole thing since yesterday. I just not sure where I did wrong here now.

Comment: Have you used libraries from this link? If not try this out. https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. The Library that I used is a version someone modified has some more features, somehow it does't work 100% when trying to rotate. Switch back, its working now, Thanks again for you time and help.